# Content-Type header lost when using custom URL

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm hosting a FireFox plugin on Google Cloud Storage. In order to be properly handled by FireFox, the Content-Type needs to be set to application/x-xpinstall

I have uploaded as follows:

```
gsutil -h "Content-Type: application/x-xpinstall" cp -a public-read \
   ActivityInfo.xpi gs://download.activityinfo.org
```

When accessed from the standard endpoint, everything is correct:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/download.activityinfo.org/ActivityInfo.xpi \ 
     -o /dev/null

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Feb 13 2013 15:53:33 (1360799613)
Expires: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 12:38:30 GMT
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 11:38:30 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 11:38:01 GMT
ETag: "1ee983889c947a204eab4db6902c9a67"
x-goog-generation: 1362051481261000
x-goog-metageneration: 1
Content-Type: application/x-xpinstall
Content-Language: en
x-goog-crc32c: a11b93ab
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5562
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, no-transform
Age: 491
```

But when I try to access from the custom domain download.activityinfo.org, the header reverts to application/octet-stream

```
$ curl -s -D - http://download.activityinfo.org/ActivityInfo.xpi -o /dev/null       
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Feb 13 2013 15:53:33 (1360799613)
Expires: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 12:10:24 GMT
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 11:10:24 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Feb 2013 20:36:24 GMT
ETag: "1ee983889c947a204eab4db6902c9a67"
x-goog-generation: 1361997384772000
x-goog-metageneration: 2
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
x-goog-crc32c: a11b93ab
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5562
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, no-transform
Age: 2298
```

I have set the CNAME to c.storage.googleapis.com per the docs

```
$ nslookup download.activityinfo.org
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  Comtrend.Home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    storage.l.googleusercontent.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:400c:c00::80
          173.194.78.128
Aliases:  download.activityinfo.org
         c.storage.googleapis.com
```

Is this a bug or do I need to change my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two results above have different values in x-goog-generation and x-goog-metageneration, which makes me suspect you have uploaded the object more than once, and you were seeing the results from different versions (which have different values for Content-Type). Do you have versioning enabled for the bucket? If not, then maybe there is some caching going on in one of the paths. Are you still seeing this behavior?

Comment: That's it! Cloudflare was enabled for this domain. Thanks for the sharp eyes!